# Retrive values from xml file in NIFI

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

I am trying to get the Ids from a xml file. Then use each Id to do another search.

```
<eSearchResult>
<Count>45</Count>
<RetMax>20</RetMax>
<RetStart>0</RetStart>
<IdList>
<Id>33361791</Id>
<Id>33361786</Id>
<Id>32332909</Id>
<Id>32025009</Id>
<Id>31802014</Id>
<Id>31802012</Id>
<Id>31723292</Id>
<Id>31723289</Id>
<Id>31217606</Id>
<Id>30820044</Id>
<Id>30783288</Id>
<Id>30783284</Id>
<Id>30723345</Id>
<Id>30602740</Id>
<Id>30487615</Id>
<Id>30429559</Id>
<Id>30275559</Id>
<Id>30209371</Id>
<Id>30158703</Id>
<Id>29991780</Id>
</IdList>
</eSearchResult>
```

I use EvaluateXPath processor,  add a custom property "id : //*/Id". But I cannot get the Ids.

How can I retrieve these Ids and put each of them into next processor?

Answer (score 0):

@duolanierduone

The solution you are looking for here is going to start with NiFi Record Readers.  For your use case XML Reader.

With a Record Reader, you are able to read data (xml) and output results (the ids you want) and/or transform to another data type (csv,json,etc) using Record Writer.   ConvertRecord, QueryRecord & UpdateRecord are useful processors here.

If you just want the ids, try sending XML to QueryRecord (configured with XML Reader) and then you create a property, for example id and set the value to:

```
SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE [value matching argument]
```

Some more details specifically on queryRecord here with screen shot samples of the property & sql like query:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-SQL-on-FlowFiles-using-QueryRecord-Processor-Apache/ta-p/246671

Comment: I tried EvalueXQuery to get the Id value, it works. The output is the id in text type. How can I use this output as a parameters and set it to invokhttp?

Comment: Does that give multiple ids downstream?... if ID downstream is an attribute, you should be able to tell invokeHttp to send the attribute in the body.  You can also use + on invokeHttp to add more attributes or test custom values to the api call.